# cambiar alert normal por un alert de sweet alert 2

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

hola trato de implementar una alerta personaliza quiero cambiar las alertas normales por unas de sweet alert dos pero no se como

por ejemplo en esta condición mando dos alertas con puedo cambiarlas a sweet alert?
ya puse las librerías pero no se como insertar el código

```
 if(res == 1){
 alert("Fallo al agregar");
 } else {
 alert("Vehículo agregado con éxito!!");
 document.getElementById("frmajax").reset();
 }
```

código de sw2:

```
Swal.fire({
  position: 'top-end',
  type: 'success',
  title: 'Your work has been saved',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aplicado a tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
if (res == 1) {
    Swal.fire({
        position: 'top-end',
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Fallo al agregar',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
    });
} else {
    Swal.fire({
        position: 'top-end',
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Vehículo agregado con éxito!!',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
    });
    document.getElementById("frmajax").reset();
}
```

Comment: perfecto funciono era muy simple pero quizás puse mal los cierres de corchetes y no me funcionaba muchas gracias , una pregunta mas me sale la ventana desplazada a la izquierda como puedo centrarla ?

Comment: Modifica position, ahora esta en 'top-end' puedes cambiar el valor por: 'top', 'top-start', 'top-end', 'center', 'center-start', 'center-end', 'bottom', 'bottom-start', o 'bottom-end'. Utiliza el que prefieras. Saludos

Comment: ok perfecto muchas gracias